# PlatformIO utility is not found

Tags: clion

Hello i am getting problems with CLion 2020 that when I try create a new PlatformIO project, it just says "PlatformIO utility is not found"
[ERROR.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NQH3.png)

Comment: Did you check the Install Guide?

Comment: Ask platformio support. This question off topic here. Do not use `C` or `C++` when you do noty ask programming questions

Comment: I followed the whole install guide. Even followed adding PATH variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The platformio.exe can usually be found at C:\Users<your_username>.platformio\penv\Scripts.

If you add that location to your path variable, clion should be able to find it.

Good luck

Comment: This did not help, still shows the same message, even after a system restart.

Comment: @MichalTrolol If you type in the Command Prompt -> pio ,does it finds something?

Comment: Aside from this, don't forget to install PlatformIO by their official guide. Like, you need to run the Python script (get-platformio.py), and then add the path to PATH as Sven says.

Answer (score 1):

For MacOS users having this problem, I had to do this:

create this folder under .local:

```
~/.local/bin
```

Then run these commands:

```
ln -s ~/.platformio/penv/bin/platformio ~/.local/bin/platformio
ln -s ~/.platformio/penv/bin/pio ~/.local/bin/pio
ln -s ~/.platformio/penv/bin/piodebuggdb ~/.local/bin/piodebuggdb
```

Go into CLion under the PlatformIO settings and delete any text in the field that wants the path to PlatformIO (I know that doesn't make sense, but trust me).

Apply and OK that, then open a new PlatformIO project ... TA DA!